# Функция mail, пометка "Важное"

Tags: email, php

Добрый день, как при использовании функции mail установить пометку (флаг) что сообщение "Важное"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ; 
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"; 
   $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n"; 
   $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n"; 
   $headers .= "Importance: High\n";        
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

[Гуглинг](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#91058)

Comment: Вообще-то в [спецификации](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822) подобных заголовков нету и не может быть, т.к. подобные пометки - это детали реализации конкретных почтовых клиентов. По этому, я очень сомневаюсь, что подобное будет работать хотя бы у 1% пользователей.

Comment: Так и есть, вариант нерабочий. Но за попытку помочь всеравно +

Comment: Опера через свой M2 тоже позволяет установить важность. и заполняет заголовок X-Priority. Правда в списке сообщений, важность в той же опере не видна. А в гугле видна, но там важность определяется не только этими заголовками (какими конкретно выяснять лениво)...
В общем если ответ подразумевает однозначный ответ, то @ROOT его дал, если вопрос провокационный под ответ "никак", то переформулируйте вопрос - для какого клиента именно вам надо. и ответ будет такой, например: шлите сами себе письмо через этот клиент с соответствующей пометкой, смотрите заголовки, эмулируйте в php.